# Why am i getting a Cannot implicitly convert type error for AppiumWebElement on a WindowsElement

Tags: c#, appium, winappdriver

I'm in the process of learning Appium with WinAppDriver. I am attemption to connect to an application already launched on the desktop e.g. 'Notepad' and then click the Maximise button.

However, the segment of code

```
WindowsElement maximizeButton = notepad.FindElementByName("Maximize");
```

Is giving me this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.AppiumWebElement' to 
'OpenQA.Selenium.Appium.Windows.WindowsElement'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I don't know why this is happening as nodepad was declared as a WindowsElement and maximizeButton is a WindowsElement. I don't get this error if i declare it as a var.

But why does WindowsElement not work?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void AttachToAnExistingAppWindow()
    {
        // https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions/a8c02cfac47b4bf0c12c571b6010c403dcfe5e7f#when-and-how-to-attach-to-an-existing-app-window
        DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", "Root");
        WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> DesktopSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), appCapabilities);

        Assert.IsNotNull(DesktopSession);

        WindowsElement notepad = DesktopSession.FindElementByName("Untitled - Notepad");
        notepad.Click();

        WindowsElement maximizeButton = notepad.FindElementByName("Maximize");
        if (!maximizeButton.Text.Contains("Maximize"))
        {
             maximizeButton.Click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well `FindElementByName` is declared to return an `AppiumWebElement`. Why would you *expect* to assign that result to a `WindowsElement` variable? It *could* return something that isn't a `WindowsElement` (at least as far as the compiler is concerned).

Comment: So if i jump to the declaration for DesktopSession.FindElementByName its a "public W FindElementByName(string name);", but if i do the same for notepad.FindElementByName("Maximize"); its "public AppiumWebElement FindElementByName(string name);". Even though i created notepad as a WindowsElement. How do resolve that or find the Maximise button on the notepad application?

Comment: If you're confident that the result *will* be a `WindowElement` (and you need it to be, in order to access WindowElement-specific members), just cast to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I found this to work..

```
WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> session;

session.FindElementByName("Maximize").Click();
session.FindElementByName("Restore").Click();

// Or using Maximize and restore via xpath
session.FindElementByXPath($"//Button[starts-with(@Name, \"Maximize\")]").Click();
session.FindElementByXPath($"//Button[starts-with(@Name, \"Restore\")]").Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try
WindowsElement maximizeButton = (WindowsElement)notepad.FindElementByName("Maximize");